Inconsistent behavior when converting between Spline Types in Edit Mode vs Geometry Nodes
I'm using Blender 4.3. Starting with a Bezier Curve object, in Edit Mode I perform Curve->Set Spline Type->NURBS with the "Handle" option not selected. This changes the curve topology as expected.
If instead I take the original Bezier curve into geometry nodes, and use the Set Spline Type node in NURBS mode, the curve topology does not change. This is equivalent to converting the Bezier into NURBS in Edit Mode with "Handle" selected.
But I want to replicate the "Handle" unselected conversion behavior in geometry nodes. What I expected to work was, in geometry nodes, converting the Bezier to a Poly spline first, and then to a NURBS curve. This removes the handle information, but the NURBS curve has a different topology again to the Edit Mode conversion.
These differences happen whether or not the curve is cyclic, and with different numbers of control points.
One thing I noticed is that the Edit Mode conversion results in a NURBS spline with a 'knots_mode' attribute of 2. Whereas the Bezier -> Poly -> NURBS conversion in geometry nodes results in a NURBS spline with a 'knots_mode' attribute of 0 or 1 depending on whether the spline is cyclic. Blender does not allow me to write to the attribute 'knots_mode'. I'm not sure if this is relevant.
So, how can I replicate the Edit Mode conversion in geometry nodes?



The problem is the object is of the wrong type. You can get GN result with the Edit Mode version, but not the other way roun since the base object is missing settings in the Object Data Properties. Something similar would be if you added Geometry Nodes to a mesh object - you can generate a curve with that, but you would not have curve settings in the Object Data Properties. You also could not apply the GN modifier and keep a curve as result - it is basically for generating mesh objects, trying to apply it gives an error: "Evaluated geometry from modifier does not contain a mesh."
